# Does minimax count as ai functionality in a tic tac toe game?

Tags: algorithm

I was under the impression that it did, as I was told to write a tic tac toe program using minimax, however, I'm not 100% sure that's the case now. Is minimax more of a brute force approach or does it count as ai functionality?

Comment: I think it's both. AI does not necessarily imply learning, just something like the ability to make better than random decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matter of opinion (tl;dr - an algo may not intrinsically be classified as AI, even if the *application of that algo to different problems* may)

---

Preliminaries:

[Ref wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence)

> In computer science, an ideal "intelligent" machine is a flexible rational agent that perceives its environment and takes actions that maximize its chance of success at some goal.
>
> [Rational agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_agent) - rational agent is an agent that has clear preferences, models **uncertainty** via expected values of variables or functions of variables, and always chooses to perform the action with the optimal expected outcome for itself from among all feasible actions.

---

My musing

As tic-tac-toe is entirely explorable, there's no **uncertainty** - therefore the **minimax application to tic-tac-toe** may fall outside the definition of AI.

But... as you notice, everything hinges on the meaning one associates to *uncertainty* - complete information games are deterministic (so that one may argue there's nothing uncertain in, say, chess), it is only the numbers of possible plays which makes impossible to exhaustively explore them, therefore requiring "intelligent choices".

Minimax applied to chess (*coupled with heuristic pruning of alternatives*) can be classified as "AI", as it would be its application in [the presence of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Minimax_in_the_face_of_uncertainty). But I don't feel that "minimax tic-tac-toe" is "intelligent" enough, artificial or not.